# Julia ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (Int64) used in boolean context

Tags: julia

I am getting the error in the title when I call a function, but not if I execute the body of the function directly. Here is the definition of my function:

```
function sslogdensity(trial::ABtrial,σ²,ł,ρ²)
    (id,Tobs,μg,y₀,y₁,yg,ξ₀ₐᵣ,ξ₀ᵣᵣ,ξ₁ₐᵣ,ξ₁ᵣᵣ,ξ₀ₐₐ,ξ₁ₐₐ,,g,gᵧ)=params(trial)
    if(gᵧ==1)
        return sslogdensity(yg,gᵧ,μg,σ²,ł,ρ²)
    else
        return 0
    end
end
```

When I call this function I get the error message:

```
julia> typeof(trial)
ABtrial

julia> sslogdensity(trial,1.0,1.0,1.0)
ERROR: TypeError: non-boolean (Int64) used in boolean context
 in sslogdensity at /home/grad/msl33/Dropbox/pprocess/statespace.jl:412
```

but if I just execute the code inside the function directly it works

```
julia> (id,Tobs,μg,y₀,y₁,yg,ξ₀ₐᵣ,ξ₀ᵣᵣ,ξ₁ₐᵣ,ξ₁ᵣᵣ,ξ₀ₐₐ,ξ₁ₐₐ,,g,gᵧ)=params(trial);

julia> if(gᵧ==1)
               return sslogdensity(yg,gᵧ,μg,σ²,ł,ρ²)
           else
               return 0
           end
-322.1504448303596
```

Can anyone provide me with any explanation for this behaviour?

EDIT:
For completeness
Line 412 from the error message corresponds to the line

```
if(gᵧ==1)
```

and

```
function params(trial::ABtrial)
    return (trial.id,trial.Tobs,trial.μg,trial.y₀,trial.y₁,trial.yg,trial.ξ₀ₐᵣ,trial.ξ₀ᵣᵣ,trial.ξ₁ₐᵣ,trial.ξ₁ᵣᵣ,trial.ξ₀ₐₐ,trial.ξ₁ₐₐ,trial.,trial.g,trial.gᵧ)
end
```

Comment: What is the value of `gᵧ` when it works and when it crashes? (*i.e.* what does `println(gᵧ)`says?)

Comment: Is this resolved? What was the problem?

Comment: I haven't actually been able to recreate the problem at present.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to say without a bit more information (definitions of `params`; any methods that may have been added to `==`), but since the only boolean context in your code is the `if` conditional, let's focus on that. Since `==` is just a function, it could be overridden depending on its arguments. To debug this, I would insert `@show gᵧ, gᵧ==1` right above that line and see what gets printed. It's possible that `gᵧ` is some kind of value such that `==` has a weird definition that's returning an `Int` instead of a `Bool` (like it should).

Answer (score -1):

When executing code in the REPL the variables are globals, and the compiler assume they can change value and type at any time. In the function however the types are generally known, and the compiler will be strict with enforcing the type rules.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `return false` instead of `return 0`. Julia tends to dislike using 1 and 0 for true/false.